# zero divisors in commutative ring with unity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose A is a commutative ring with unity. prove if a,b ∈ A, with a not equal to 0, prove if a(b + 1  <sub>A</sub> ) = b(a + a) then a is a zero divisor or b = 1  <sub>A</sub>.

This is what I have so far- 
just using basic algebra:

a (b + 1) = ab + a

b (a + a) = ab + ab

Therefore a = ab

Does this arithmetic even hold when using rings? And if it does, how do I use it to show that a is a zero divisor? By definition, if my arithmetic holds, then b must be a unit in A.

Comment: Your arithmetic does not show that b must be a unit in A. It shows that $a(1-b)=0$. So either $b=1$, or if not, then $a$ is a zero divisor (because there is a non-zero element, specifically $1-b$, which becomes zero after multiplication by $a$ - precisely what it means for $a$ to be a zero divisor). Yes, the arithmetic holds, because it is only dependent on the axioms - commutativity, associativity, distributivity, multiplicative unit etc. - that are required to hold, by definition, in a commutative ring with unity.

Comment: okay, I understand now. Thank you so much!